# How to check if the Menubar contains no items?

Tags: plugins, menus

I'm using the [Menubar plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/menubar/) to place a menu at the top of my website. However, I need to find a way to check if the menu contains items or not. My menu is called 'menubar'. Currently, I'm loading the menu like so:

```
do_action('wp_menubar', "menubar");
```

It loads fine, but I need to check if there are items in it or not so I can adjust and display other things instead. Any ideas? Or is this question too vague?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $meniu = count(wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'menubar' )));
                       if($meniu > 0 ){
                           //here goes your stuff if we have items in menu
                       }
```

Comment: You may want to prevent the display by adding `'echo' => FALSE,` to the first `wp_nav_menu` argument.